# Create row with every CSV value

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2000

```
ID          Dates                                          Qty      Secs    DayPart

CO138491-02 06/10/2013,06/11/2013,06/12/2013,06/13/2013    4        6.00    Morning
```

How can I change those comma separated values and  have result like this without using CTE coz i am on SQL SERVER 2000, and its better if we don't use  a loop coz latter the data is going to be huge

```
CO138491-02 06/10/2013  4   6.00    Morning
CO138491-02 06/11/2013  4   6.00    Morning
CO138491-02 06/12/2013  4   6.00    Morning
CO138491-02 06/13/2013  4   6.00    Morning
```

Any hint would be appreciated or any link to limit my search

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this

```
SELECT          a.ID,
                SUBSTRING(',' + a.Dates + ',', n.Number + 1, CHARINDEX(',', ',' + a.Dates + ',', n.Number + 1) - n.Number - 1) AS [Value]
                , [Qty], [Secs], [DayPart]
FROM            Table1 AS a
INNER JOIN      master..spt_values AS n ON SUBSTRING(',' + a.Dates + ',', n.Number, 1) = ','
WHERE           n.Type = 'p'
                AND n.Number > 0 
                AND n.Number < LEN(',' + a.Dates + ',')
```

Check the below link for reference

http://www.codeproject.com/Questions/526739/ConvertplusColumnplusdataplusintoplusRowsplusthrou

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want use CTE or loops, try use approach with additional table of numbers:

See http://www.sommarskog.se/arrays-in-sql-2000.html#tblnum-core

Something like:

```
CREATE FUNCTION inline_split_me (@param varchar(7998)) RETURNS TABLE AS
   RETURN(SELECT substring(',' + @param + ',', Number + 1,
                    charindex(',', ',' + @param + ',', Number + 1) - Number - 1)
                 AS Value
          FROM   Numbers
          WHERE  Number <= len(',' + @param + ',') - 1
            AND  substring(',' + @param + ',', Number, 1) = ',')
```

Comment: Actually I don't want a splitter rather each value with splitted strings, in addition since its a huge data is it wise to use a function??

Comment: I do not know another way, except function in this case. The most effective way is use of CLR function, but it dosn't work in MSSQL2000